# How to select specific Outgoing email server for sending emails - Odoo 13

Tags: python, odoo, crm

I have two email servers set up.

Lets say hr@example.com and marketing@example.com. I am sending emails from code(scheduled actions).

What I want is, When its a email regarding HR, it should use hr@example.com and when it is regarding marketing, it uses marketing@example.com.

How may I achieve this?

I am looking for something like

```
template_id.send(outgoing_server="someID123")
```

Answer (score 0):

First but probably not the best solution is to use multiple mail templates for this. Because you can set a mail server on templates already.

Another solution, which i didn't and won't test, is to set a default `mail_server_id` by using the context. I'm not sure if Odoo will use the context on the whole chain from "send-something-call" to "really-send-an-email-now-call". Keep in mind that a lot of code/calls are between those two.

But you can try following:

```py
my_mail_server_id = 2  # or whatever you want to do here to get it

# use a template like in your question
template.with_context(default_mail_server_id=my_mail_server_id).send_mail()

# or posting a message on a record eg. a project.task
body = "Hello World"
task.with_context(default_mail_server_id=my_mail_server_id).message_post(body)
```

That should set the desired mail server to in the process created `mail.message` on field `mail_server_id`, which in the end should lead to a `mail.mail` which will be send by using the desired server.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But How may I get `my_mail_server_id` ? You hard coded 2, but how can I get ID of my specific mail server?

Comment: That's something you have to do yourself. Using hardcoded IDs is IMO not an optimal way to do that and was used here to have a simple example. You can extend the settings with some new options using system/config parameters for example. In the end that will be your decision. Oh and when using my first solution, you don't have to think about it, because that's a field on the templates and can be configured in every template in the formular view.